# How can I teleport to an unloaded entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am using invisible invulnerable ArmorStands to create "warps" and "homes" in a map. The idea is that I can spawn them in with a specific name, and then teleport a player back to them like this:

```
/tp @p @e[name=PlayerHome,type=ArmorStand]
```

**These warps/homes need to be able to be moved, so I cannot just use static coordinates.**

The ArmorStand method was working fine at first, however I have noticed that if the entity is not within spawn chunks or a radius of the player, I cannot teleport or interact with it in any way.

Is there any way I can teleport to a far-away entity? Or have it become loaded first?

I was thinking of doing something with /spreadplayers, which loads chunks that entities are spread to, but I cannot get it to target the unloaded ArmorStand.

Comment: Take a look at [this video](http://youtu.be/-UUYQL4tj7c). It changes the spawn location in order to target an entity there, although this may not be appropriate for you.

Comment: @MBraedley A good lead, although, as there is only one worldspawnpoint, it can only work with a single warp.

Comment: I don't know much about command blocks, but it seems like if you needed to change the coords of a warp, you would have to run a command to change the location of the armor stands. Couldn't you instead run a command to change the command in another command block? I thought command modification was part of a recent update.

Comment: @Johonn You can, but you can only change it to what is typed into the command that is changing the the other command block. I want to be able to move it dynamically, say, with a /trigger SetHome command. If you can find a way to get player coordinates into a command block though, that would work.

Comment: What exact functionality are you trying to implement? You say getting player coordinates would work. How would that solve your problem? I'm not sure I totally understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Johonn My end goal is to create warps/sethomes that can be moved to any coordinates. If I could set a command block to a player's coordinates, then I could also set homes like that.

Comment: So a player will be at the location when the warp is initially set, correct?

Comment: @Johonn The player will teleport to the warp/home where it was last set, not the first place that it was set.

Comment: But if the warp needs to be moved, there will be a player at the new location to move it, right?

Comment: @Johonn Oh, yes.

Comment: When you create the armor stand, could you also create a chunkloader using hoppers? Depending on how many warps you want to have at once, it might not noticeably lag the world. However, this would change the mechanics of the game and people could misuse that to create farms that are always loaded, possibly.

Comment: @Johonn If there's a way to load the single chunk that the stand is in, then that'd be a great solution. 256 chunks are already constantly loaded at spawn, so a few extra shouldn't make a difference. Although is there a chunk loader design that could do this? All of the ones I've seen require a massive trail of chunks all the way back to spawn, which wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Perhaps this video [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8dv9P49cKk] would be helpful; or perhaps you've already seen it. There are a couple of caveats: it is a "lazy" chunk, and it will unload again after a short amount of time. However, if you do a 5x5 grid of chunks with this, you might be able to teleport to the center one which will be a normally loaded chunk. There might be a way for you to set it up to utilize that - I don't know much about your system so can't say for sure (not to mention I don't use these mechanics myself at all).

Comment: @Johonn Problem with that is I would still need coordinates to load the chunk at.

Comment: Good point. TBH I was mostly trying to get more info about the problem in case it was helpful to someone else, as I don't really deal with this kind of stuff myself. Glad to see it looks like someone solved it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can spawn a redstone block a certain numbers above or below the point of the player with an activator rail ontop. Then spawn a command minecart on the activator rail with the command `/spreadplayers ~ ~ 1 false @e[name=PlayerHome,type=ArmorStand,c=1,r=2]`.

Because the `/spreadplayers` will load the chunk the entity is spread to, the commandblock minecart on the activator rail will permenantly keep the chunk that the armorstand is in loaded. When moving the point, run a fill command and a kill command at the previous home to remove the traces. When you are teleporting the player back to their home, you can simply offset the teleportation by a few blocks in the y coordinate.

Comment: Nice solution! Unless there are any improvements onto this (such as not using a clock for each warp) this'll get the bounty. Also, spreading an armorstand/entity that isn't the player home armorstand means that I don't have to worry about offsetting the Y, and can have this device right at bedrock.

Comment: Wait.. Does it mean that /spreadplayers actually affect unloaded entities? I thought it only affects loaded entities.

Comment: No the way this works is because the player is there when the point is set, the chunk is loaded. this device doesn't load an unloaded chunk, it simply prevents the chunk from unloading.

Comment: Btw this may not work after the world is reloaded

Answer (score 0):

You can always just use this command if your server is in 1.14:

```
/forceload add < 1stchunk > < 2ndchunk >
```

just as if you were using `/fill`, put the xz of the first chunk location in the `< 1stchunk >`, and put the xz of the second chunk in the `< 2ndchunk >`. This will cause the specified chunks to always be loaded. Just be warned that this won't work if your server involves laggy things such as redstone, as if redstone is loaded in the lot, it will get very laggy.

Answer (score -5):

Just run this command and replace the *name* with the entity's name: `/execute @e[name=*name*] ~ ~ ~ /tp @p @e[name=*name*]`

Comment: Can you prove that this will work under the conditions set out by the asker?  Additionally, it might not take the proper player, since it's executing from the entity position.