# Teleport to Armor Stand in Unloaded Chunk

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to teleport players to an armor stand in an unloaded chunk. I've tried researching how to do this. Some answers say that it is not possible. Other answers say to use the @s selector. I've tried using the @s selector, but I don't think I understand enough about coding to make it work correctly.

I have been able to successfully teleport myself to an armor stand with the custom name of "Here."

```
/execute at @e[type=minecraft:armor_stand,name=Here] run tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

However, when I place the armor stand in an unloaded chunk, I cannot teleport to it. I've tried replacing @e with @s--but then the command stops functioning completely.

Here is the code that does not work:

```
/execute at @s[type=minecraft:armor_stand,name=Here] run tp @p ~ ~ ~
```

What should I be doing differently? Is it possible to teleport to an armor stand in an unloaded chunk?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I teleport to an unloaded entity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183416/how-can-i-teleport-to-an-unloaded-entity)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I was hoping that there was an easy way to teleport to an unloaded entity using @s selector. If that isn't the case, then I will test out the /forceload option to see if that works.

Comment: Do any of the answers here answer your question: [How can I teleport to an unloaded entity?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/183416/4797)

Comment: As long as the armor stand is in an unloaded chunk the command will not find it, thus making it unable to perform the command.